# how to auto input my location in map api

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps

How to get lat and lng from current location and insert in my code?

below is my code.

```
  var map;
 var geocoder;

        function initialize()       
          {
    var myLatlong   =   new google.maps.LatLng(23.6139  , 77.2090);

    var myOptions   =   {
                                zoom:5,
                                center:myLatlong,                                        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.Satellite
                        };

 map =   new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),myOptions);
geocoder   = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    function initMap() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
        lat: -34.397,
        lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 6
});
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    map: map
});

if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
        map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
} else {
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
}
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ? 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' : 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
}
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: can I get code only for fetching my current location, I will add it as my center position in map. this code has more features than needed.

Comment: I've edited my answer as your requirement. Use this. I think it'll work. Thanks.